# I want to extract multiple data points in an excel cell which is separated by a character

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I have the following:

abcd-12-345-678

I need to extract the 12 to a cell, 345 to a separate cell, and 678 to another.

The length of the numbers are not consistent throughout the list.
Example it could be abcd-123-34-6789

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming  you don't need the *abcd*, with data in **A1**, in **B1** enter:

```
=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE($A1,"-",REPT(" ",999)),COLUMNS($A:B)*999-998,999))
```

and copy across:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Go to Data

select Text to Columns
In Convert Text to Columns Wizard. Select the separator you have. 
Click Delimited > Next

And you can select the destination to the data to be stored.